# Center two lines of text on web page vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get all of the content on my page to be centered horizontally and vertically, and I have looked at multiple different ways of doing it, however they don't seem to be working, and I am unsure why.

I will be having three different lines of text, all in different H tags, and they all need to be in the center of the page

e.g: http://gyazo.com/ffb698f181f428217fc9dc282969c190

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900);

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:center;
}

h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background:#000;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  display: table;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<title>Callum Watson</title>
        
</head>
 
<body>

<div id="content">
  <h1> CALLUM WATSON </h1>
  <h2>all css?! WHUT.</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unsure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `display: table-cell;` and the 'new' units `vw` (viewport width) and `vh` (viewport height) :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content {
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  background:#000;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1> CALLUM WATSON </h1>
  <h2>all css?! WHUT.</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `h1{display:block}` instead of `table-cell`

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900);

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:center;
}

h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background:#000;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  display: table;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<title>Callum Watson</title>
        
</head>
 
<body>

<div id="content">
  <h1> CALLUM WATSON </h1>
  <h2>all css?! WHUT.</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's back at the top again, I need it horizontally centered

Comment: Ops, my fault. I didnt run the code on full page, sorry. I will try it again.